# How to add a env created via terminal

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, wsl-2

I use pycharm pro, on windows 10 and I had to install a ubuntu wsl. Now I created a environment using python virtualenv, as:

```
virtualenv myenv -p python3.7.3
```

I tried to create the environment directly on pycharm terminal, on the wsl path such as mnt/c/User/myname/myProject. using pycharm terminal i can switch to the new environment, but the change in environment is not reflected at the bottom left corner.

How can i add this environment to pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

To add an existing virtualenv in PyCharm you can use the following procedure. 
Click on

```
File -> Settings -> Project: <your project> -> Python Interpreter
```

Now click on the gear icon at the top-right corner of the window and choose *Add*.

Then, in the section dedicated to Existing Environment you have to choose the interpreter, this means the python.exe file of your existing virtualenv.

When this has been done, you have it in Pycharm.

Comment: thanks but I know that, the issue is that the env needs to be created in /home/ on the wsl